# Is it possible to execute local .exe´s from angular application running in browser?

Tags: node.js, angular

We are about to start a new project which should be like a desktop app but still run inside a browser for creating items in a system. After these items are created, an .EXE file on the LOCAL machine must be called to do some code generation. Is this possible if using Angular to develop the application or do we need third party libs for executing local .exe's?

Comment: Probably something like Electron

Comment: yeah but Electron runs natively right? Would sure be nice if it was possible to still run the application within the confines of the browser

Comment: Can't make any sense of your question.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible out of the box. Browsers make *very* sure that local executables cannot be started. You would have to look for other solutions.

One possible idea, depending on how much effort you want to invest, would be to compile the WebKit engine yourself, i.e., create a binary "wrapper" which runs the browser engine itself. Then you are free to extend it in whatever fashion you need, including adding the possibility to start local .exe's (or if those .exe's are your own applications, you could compile them right into your WebKit wrapper).

Comment: thanks that helped :) But i guess using Electron as previosly stated would work but of course make it a native app right?

Comment: Well, sure, Electron is somewhat like what I describe, just "more". Check out the Electron documentation. Your question mentions AngularJS, and that is just that - JS.